# Lazy loading of images breaks anchor links

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, anchor, lazy-loading

I have a one page website in which I use this script to lazy load the images: http://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload
Now, I also have anchor links on that page, like `#footer`. When the script is enabled, anchor links pointing to a position below a lazy loaded image break because when the image is loaded, the content gets pushed down.

So somehow the position needs to be recalculated, but I can't wrap my head around the technique behind this. I found a bug report from Mozilla with the exact same problem here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=718321, but still I am unable to understand how they solved it. Looking at their Git changelog [here](https://github.com/mozilla/kitsune/commit/663d946) actually shows how they solved that problem, but because I don't understand the steps necessary I am unable to recreate that.

How do I recalculate the anchor position to make anchor links working again, even with lazy loading enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've had a good read on lazy loading images and I also managed to fix my problem described above, but in the end I didn't use it. Why you ask? Because although lazy loading images has some advantages, there are always many disadvantages - problems with touch devices, older browser & Internet Explorer and of course SEO, because Google's bots won't execute JavaScript or go into `<noscript>`tags, so all they see are the placeholder images.

Comment: Actually Google bots seem to execute JavaScript at least to some extent. For example check the preview image of this search: http://goo.gl/R91IT Preview image shows lazyloaded images and not the grey placeholder.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an implementation that works by using my own jQuery animation.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#myDestinationAnchor" class="someClassName">Location</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
   // When the user clicks on an anchor with a class name "someClassName"...
$('body').on('click', 'a.someClassName', function(e) {

    // Get the hash. In this example, "#myDestinationAnchor".
    var targetSelector = this.hash;
    var $target = $(targetSelector);

    // Animate the scroll to the destination...
    $('html, body').animate(
        {
            scrollTop: $target.offset().top // Scroll to this location.
        }, {
            // Set the duration long enough to allow time
            // to lazy load the elements.
            duration: 2000,

            // At each animation step, check whether the target has moved.
            step: function( now, fx ) {

                // Where is the target now located on the page?
                // i.e. its location will change as images etc. are lazy loaded
                var newOffset = $target.offset().top;

                // If where we were originally planning to scroll to is not
                // the same as the new offset (newOffset) then change where
                // the animation is scrolling to (fx.end).
                if(fx.end !== newOffset)
                    fx.end = newOffset;
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Reference for [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

P.S. I'm using the [jQuery Lazy](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy) plugin for the lazy loading. There is no particular dependency on this plugin (that I am aware of) but I figured I would mention it.

Comment: worked perfectly even with small animation duration, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I think the duration is calculated for the scroll between the top of page to the current offset top (before images are loaded), so say it wants to scroll 2000px in 2000ms, when the final position is 4000px away. It starts moving slowly at 1px per ms and some images are loaded and suddenly the time is up, the new offset is calculated, but it only takes into account the images that loaded in the short scroll...

Comment: This method will not work on slow connections. The key is "long enough to allow time to lazy load the elements", that time doesn't exist. Anyhow, this will work in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Was going to ask you to detail how you fixed the problem (before you chose not to use it) as I have to use lazyloading. However I've worked out a solution for myself. Given my site is a one pager / linear experience ( http://thomasgrist.tumblr.com/ ) that just jumps to next anchor again and again I only need to load a certain amount in advance (of being visible in viewport) for which I can use the threshold setting in the lazyload plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload (thanks anyway, you put me on the right path)